# Why does p not show the same address as a?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-address

I'm learning about pointers in arrays in C. I'm really confused as to what an array of pointers really is. Have a look at this example-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int *p[] = { a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4 };

    printf( "%p %p %p %d ", p, *p, a, *(*p));
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program I'm getting different addresses for `a` and `p`. Why? As far as I know, `a` is a pointer to the zeroth element of the array and `p` is a pointer to pointer. `a` is pointing to the zeroth element's address, but what about `p`? Is there anything like address of address?

Comment: a is not a pointer, a is an array.  p is also not a pointer, it is also an array.

Comment: @MooingDuck they all decay to pointer in the `printf` statement though

Answer (score 1):

An address is made of bits, and anything made of bits can be put in memory. Everything in memory has an address.

This doesn't mean that every address value in a program *is* in memory. Addresses can also be temporary values that are used as part of an expression.

The same applies integer values. Some of them are in memory and some aren't. You can have this:

```
int i = 7;
int *p = &i;
```

but you can't have this:

```
int *q = &7;
```

`i` is the name of a variable existing in memory, and you can get its address with `&`. The value 7 is stored at that address. `&7` doesn't work because the existence of the literal `7` in the program source code isn't enough to cause the value 7 to exist in memory at run time.

In slightly more technical terms, `i` is an *lvalue* and `7` is an *rvalue*. The prefix `&` operator requires its operand to be an lvalue, but it doesn't produce an lvalue result. `&i` is an rvalue, just like `7`. That's why `&(&i)` is invalid.

Comment: Thankyou alot! :) As far as i underatand by you answer is that &(&a) =2 is illegal because &a is afterall a hexadeximal integer and we can use & with any integer and therefore it is illegal.Right?

Answer (score 1):

Think of variables as aliases for addresses. When you have

```
int v1 = 10;
```

`v1` is an alias for an address that holds `10`.

When you have:

```
int* v2 = &v1;
```

`v2` is an alias for an address that holds the address of `v1`.

An address can hold a value that can be other addresses or raw values such as `int`s, `char`s, etc.

To answer your question,

> Is there anything like address of address?

Strictly speaking the answer is no. But if you have:

```
int** v3 = &v2;
```

then, `v3` is alias for an address that has the value of an address which has the value of an address which has an `int` as its value.

In your case,

```
static int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int *p[] = { a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4 };
```

`a` is an array, an array of `int`s. When used in an expression, it decays to a pointer. `a`, `a+1`, etc. evaluate to pointers to `int`s.

`p` is also an array, an array of `int*`s. When used in an expression, it decays to a pointer. `p`, `p+1`, etc. evaluate to pointers to `int*`s.

`p` evaluates to an address that holds an `int*` - `a`.
`a` evaluates to an address that holds an `int` - `0`.

`*p` evaluates to `a`.
`*a` evaluates to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

No two variables may have the same address in C.

The array `a` and the array `p` are variables. So they must have different addresses.

Here is another example:

```
int x[3] = { 0, 1, 2 } ;
int y[3] = { 0, 1, 2 };

printf("%p %p\n", &x , &y);
```

It makes no difference that the arrays in your example store a different data type than `int`.

Also, the first element of an array always resides at the start of the array, so outputting `x` (which decays to `&x[0]` when you try to print its value) will get the same result as `&x`.

Answer (score 0):

**p** *points to* the first location of the block of memory containing:

```
{ a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4 }
```

**a** *points* the first location of the block of memory containing

```
{0,1,2,3,4}
```

These two are thus pointing to different memory chunks.

**p[0]** (or ***p**) and **a** should have the same address.

Comment: how it is possible that there is anything like address of address?

Comment: @LishaGuPta You need to store the memory address somewhere.  Where are you storing it?

Comment: if its legal  than &&a=2 should also be legal

Comment: "**p** holds the address..." is completely wrong. `p` is the **name** of an array (a region of memory) that holds 5 pointers. Using `p` in an expression will (with some exceptions) **convert** it to a pointer to its first element. (Same for `a`).

Comment: I concede that I should've said **p points to...** instead of **contains the address of**. (same for a)

Answer (score 0):

Just think about things are organized in memory :

a : a contiguous memory zone containing 5 integers to 0 to 4 included - a is an array and `&a` == `&(a[0])` (and is also the same as `a`)

p is an array of pointers to int : it is in turn a contiguous memory zone containing 5 *pointers*. p is an array and as such `p == &(p[0])`. But now `p[0]` is a pointer containing the address of `a`.

So `p` is the address of a memory zone that contains the address of `a` : it is in fact the address of an address

So of course : `*p` (or `p[0]`)is the same as `a` and `**p` is `a[0]`. But as for any array `p` is **not** the same as `p[0]`

Comment: Nitpick: `p` is (usually) converted to an pointer to its first element, which results in a pointer to a region of memory containing **one** pointer. **However**, `&p` is different. It results in a pointer to a region of memory containing **five** pointers. The types of `p` and `&p` are not the same.

Comment: @NisseEngström : you are true. They have same value, but do not represent same type.